# MultiLine Query in Snowflake Stored Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to build one stored procedure in snowflake which will

i.   Delete existing records from dimension table.
ii.  Insert the records into the dimension table from corresponding materialized view.
iii. Once the data is inserted, record the entry into a config table.

First two are running fine, third one is not working, code below

Table DIM_ROWCOUNT

```
CREATE TABLE ANALYTICSLAYER.AN_MEDALLIA_P.DIM_ROWCOUNT
(
    "TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR(500),
    "VIEW_NAME" VARCHAR(500),
    "TABLE_ROWCOUNT" VARCHAR(500) ,
    "VIEW_ROWCOUNT" VARCHAR(500),
    "LOADDATE" timestamp

)
```

The SP has parameter as SRC_TABLE_NAME which should be loaded for column : TABLE_NAME,
VIEW_NAME will be derived inside code.
TABLE_ROWCOUNT and VIEW_ROWCOUNT will be calculated within the code.
I need to have a multi line query for insertion.
How to create the insert statement multiline?

```
   var config_details = `INSERT INTO DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME
                             SELECT '${VAR_TABLE_NAME}','${VAR_VIEW_NAME}','${VAR_TABLE_ROW_COUNT}','${VAR_VIEW_ROW_COUNT}',getdate();`
                                
       var exec_config_details = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: config_details} );
       var result_exec_config_details = exec_config_details.execute();
         result_exec_config_details.next();
```

Any help in appreciated.

Comment: Hi - can you give an example of what you expect the SELECT statement to look like when all the variables are resolved?

Comment: Hi @NickW, It should be like below INSERT INTO DBNAME.TEST_P.DIM_ROWCOUNT 
SELECT 'TABLE1' , 'VIEW1', '30', '30', GETDATE()

Answer (score 0):

I tend to write complex SQL statements in a javascript SP by appending each line/portion of text to the variable, as I find it easier to read/debug

Something like this should work (though I haven't tested it so there may be typos). Note that to get single quotes round each value I am escaping them in the code (\'):

```
var insert_DIM_ROWCOUNT = 'INSERT INTO DBNAME.TEST_P.DIM_ROWCOUNT '; 
insert_DIM_ROWCOUNT += 'SELECT \'' + SRC_TABLE_NAME + '\', \'' + VIEW_NAME + '\', \'';
insert_DIM_ROWCOUNT += TABLE_ROWCOUNT + '\', \'' + VIEW_ROWCOUNT + '\', ';
insert_DIM_ROWCOUNT += GETDATE();
```

I then test this to make sure the SQL statement being created is what I want by adding a temporary line of code, after this, to just return the SQL string:

```
return insert_DIM_ROWCOUNT;
```

Once I'm happy the SQL is correct I then comment out/delete this line and let the SQL execute.

Comment: I am trying to do something like below, but it errors out

Comment: var config_details = `INSERT INTO DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME
                             SELECT '${VAR_TABLE_NAME}','${VAR_VIEW_NAME}','${VAR_TABLE_ROW_COUNT}','${VAR_VIEW_ROW_COUNT}',getdate();`
                                
       var exec_config_details = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: config_details} );
       var result_exec_config_details = exec_config_details.execute();
         result_exec_config_details.next();

Comment: If you put variables in single quotes like that then they are going to be treated as strings and not get resolved. You need to construct your sql statement by concatenating the strings you need with the variables that need to be resolved. If your strings need to include quotes then they have to be escaped: ‘\’’